# Angularjs 1.5 vs boostrap.js Compatibility

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have some compatibility problems with AngularJS 1.5 and Boostrap.js.

I tried some versions without success. I created a plunkr to exemplify that an typeahead input doesn't work.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selected" uib-typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control">
```

[plunkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/xMTHcd91NiBL0FnZO8Qd?p=preview)

Comment: You should use angular-ui instead for AngularJS. https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: using old version of angular-ui-bootstrap and also note that current version is not tested for angular 1.5. Also get rid of bootstrap.js.

Comment: I created a new version and it doesn't work too.  [PLUNKR UPDATE](http://plnkr.co/edit/cRAyYBCRCvbSX2ByPKyQ?p=preview)

Comment: Did you try with a `1.4` series of angular, or check repo if there is  beta version of angular-ui compatible with angular 1.5?

Comment: Is there any place where I can check angular-ui compatibility to angular.js ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make two changes to your code:

1. in script.js,

change

```
var scotchApp = angular.module('scotchApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

to

```
var scotchApp = angular.module('scotchApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

2. in home.html,

change

```
typeahead="state for state in states...
```

to

```
uib-typeahead="state for state in states...
```